# :hover to stay active when cursor over dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with a dropdown menu. I would like, on hover, the  sub menu to appear. When the users mouse exits the parent and moves to the list, I need the list to stay, allowing the user to browse such.

How could this be achieved?

I'm using the following css to drop the menu down when the parents hovered:

```
#ddOne:hover ~ ul {
    background-color: red;
    display: block !important;
}
```

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLbfqrpf/) of my issue. Thanks!

The full code:

```css
  #mainMenuBar li ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #mainMenuBar {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
  }
  #mainMenuBar li {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5px auto;
    border: 0px solid #F00;
    min-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  #mainMenuBar ul li {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
  }
  #mainMenuBar li ul,
  #mainMenuBar li ul li ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #mainMenuBar li ul li ul {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 641px) {
    #mainMenuBar {
      display: block;
      color: white;
    }
    #ddOne:hover ~ ul,
    #mainMenuBar li ul:hover ~ ul {
      background-color: red;
      display: block !important;
    }
    #mainMenuBar li {
      width: auto;
      float: left;
      padding: 0px 1.4%;
      min-height: 0;
    }
    #mainMenuBar li a {
      /* margin-bottom: -25px;
    height: 50px;
    */
    }
    #mainMenuBar li ul {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #333;
      height: 100px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      border-top: 1px solid red;
      margin-top: 6px;
    }
    #mainMenuBar {
      display: block;
    }
    #mainMenuBar li ul li {
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;
    }
    #mainMenuBar li ul li ul {
      margin-left: 148px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<ul id="mainMenuBar">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown" id="ddOne">Cigarette Types +</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown" id="subTwo">A - D +</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Argentinean Sylvestris</li>
          <li>Aztec Rustica</li>
          <li>Banana Leaf</li>
          <li>Big Gem</li>
          <li>Blue Tree Glaucia</li>
          <li>Burley Oridinal</li>
          <li>Burley Variation</li>
          <li>Catterton</li>
          <li>Cherry Red</li>
          <li>Connecticut Broard Leaf</li>
          <li>Cuban Havana 142</li>
          <li>Del Gold</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown" id="subTwo">E - O +</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown" id="subTwo">P - T +</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown" id="subTwo">U - Z +</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Third Level</li>
          <li>Third Level</li>
          <li>Sub Three</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cigar Types</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hasSub"><a href="#" class="dropdown">Pipe Types+</a>
    <ul>
      <li>sub 2</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown" id="subTwo">sub1.1+</a>
        <ul>
          <li>testt</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pelleted Seeds</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Strong  Types</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ddOne:hover ~ ul, #ddOne ~ ul:hover {
    background-color: red;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Cannot open your fiddle (company network) but this should do it :)

Comment: thanks, I had a margin-top set that was pushing the bottom box away and causing the issue. Help is much apprecaited

Comment: Although this answer is correct, I would not recommend to use `:hover` for menu as it is very hard or even impossible to navigate menu using touch screen devices. You could check out Bootstrap framework (http://getbootstrap.com/) as you probably don't want to re-invent bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your structure you can use this:

```
#mainMenuBar ul {
    display:none;
}
#mainMenuBar li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

And you can't separate with `margin` the submenu since it will break the zone of the hover:

```
#mainMenuBar li ul {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #333;
        height: 100px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid red;
        /*margin-top: 6px; REMOVE THIS*/
}
```

#### [UpdateFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLbfqrpf/12/)

Comment: To replace the margin, you can use a border, for example :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the gap between `href` element and second menu level.

Change  `#ddOne:hover{...}` rule with this:

```
#ddOne {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#ddOne:hover ~ ul, #ddOne ~ ul:hover {
    background-color: red;
    display: block !important;
}
```

See it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/uLbfqrpf/16/

**I would not recommend to base menu on `:hover` because that would make site unusable on touch screen devices.**